# What is the equivalent of JavaScript console.count() in Java?

Tags: java

In Javascript there is a option to print a string with its count of getting printed using **console.count("ExampleString")**.  This is very useful in debugging  by printing a run time created string. Is there anything available like this in JAVA ?

***EDITED :***

Thank you for the downvotes !!

I have written a snippet in Java to achieve what console.count does.

```
final Map<String,Integer> hitCountStore = new HashMap<>();
void countHit(  String str )
{
if(hitCountStore.containsKey(str))
{
int var = hitCountStore.get(str).intValue();
hitCountStore.put(str, ++var);
}
else
{
hitCountStore.put(str, 1);
}
System.out.println( str + " >> " + hitCountStore.get(str));
}
```

Comment: There is none. You'll have to implement your own solution.

Comment: `System.out.println(str + " >> " + hitCountStore.merge(str, 1, (a,b) -> a+b));` would be a much easier way to implement `countHit`.

Comment: Hi Andy, what version of java is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I got confused myself `console.count()` with `console.log()`;

As per my understanding, there is no default feature available within Java that would let you know the number of times a particular method or function is called with a certain argument.

However, you could implement custom logic that would let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in standard APIs.

You would have to either implement it yourself, or find a library which provides it.